# Strange behaviour when assigning range to variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently facing a very strange situation for which I am looking some explanations.

Basically, I have an Excel workbook with some buttons that hide / unhide some ranges.

The code is as below :

```
Sub HideMyRange()
    Dim RngA as Range
    Set RngA = Range("MyRange")
    RngA.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

The code gives a 1004 execution error on the line `Set RngA = Range("MyRange")`

I thought there was an error in the spelling or what MyRange refers to so I went to check. I have MyRange correctly defined at workbook level and here is the reference : `=Recap!$D$133:$D$146;Recap!$D$273:$D$286`.

If I double click on the named range to modify the name, I get this as a refence : `=Recap!R133C4:R146C4;Recap!R273C4:R286C4`, but only while in debug mode. If I go in there while the code is not running, I am still getting the xlA1 notation.

So I had the weird idea to copy my xlA1 reference, then paste it over the xlR1C1 reference when the code is running, through the Names Manager. Now is the strange thing: after I've done that, I get no more error and the code is running just fine.

I have tried changing my code with `ThisWorkbook.Names(rngName1).RefersToRange` but I keep getting an error. I have also tried adding `Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1` in my code but that doesn't make any difference to my issue.

Is there something I am missing? I had to repeat the process for all my defined names, and after I've done so, I can't replicate the error again.

Comment: If your reference is as you show (with the quotation marks) , then your reference appears to be a string, not a range.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: no there are no quotation marks, I got mixed up with the mark to display the text as code. I've removed them from the original question

Comment: I remember having that behaviour way back and I just started using `Application.Names(pName).RefersToRange` instead (replace `pName` with the name -- I use this in a Utils module, hence the parameter instead of a name). Try it. Maybe it'll help.

Comment: Is your code inside a worksheet module? Does it make a difference if you move it to a standard module?

Comment: In my case it is in a standard module. I expect it to work in both places.

Comment: I cannot repro your problem.  What happens if, from the worksheet, you delete the `myRange` as a name,  and then recreate it manually from the worksheet?  The switching of `A1` vs `R1C1` references is also odd.